# Extracting birthday from a VARCHAR2 (EU Identification Number)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, varchar

I have a string that looks like this:

```
1890602170089
```

While this number (the actual type is VARCHAR2) doesn't mean anything, here's a brief explanation:

- `1`, the first digit: 1 stands for male, 2 stands for female
- `89 06 02`: 2nd June 1989
- `170089`: random generated stuff that I don't need

I need to extract the birthday from this string and convert it to a DATE type. Is there anything built-in that can do this or do I need to do it by myself? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: so, you can't know if soemone was born in 1912 or 2012?

Comment: well, we don't have many people here that are 102 years old :) (after year 200_ there is a different ID number that starts with a 3 or 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work from testing in fiddle.

```
--your original test data 06/02/1989
select date(substring(1890602170089, 2, 6))

-- 06/02/2013
select date(substring(1130602170089, 2, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
select (case when eid like '1%' then to_date('19'||substr(eid, 2, 6), 'YYYYMMDD')
             when eid like '3%' then to_date('20'||substr(eid, 2, 6), 'YYYYMMDD')
        end)
from (select '1890602170089' as eid
      from dual
     ) t;
```